# Ruby auto deleting temp file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm confused. Here's my code:

```
require 'csv'                                                               
require 'tempfile'                                                          

f = Tempfile.new('csv','/tmp')                                                 
f.write 'just wanna test'                                                       
f.close                                                                        

p f.path
```

If I open the output path, it is empty.

I think this is because that the TempFile got automatically removed from the file system each time the ruby session exits. However, how do I know exactly when the file got deleted? Because I'm thinking to use it to create temp file within my rails app, I'm afraid if the file got deleted before it is used.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From docs:

> When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is automatically deleted.

So, as long as you have your `f` in scope, it will not be deleted. If you exit Ruby, it will be deleted. If you are still in Ruby but `f` has fallen out of scope, it is indeterminate (probably not deleted, but not guaranteed to exist, and should not be used.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer... Could have saved me time writing had I looked.

Comment: @Myst: No worries, I think we were like 5-10 seconds from each other.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen `Tempfile` being garbage collected in the same process when I created many temp files to be zipped. In the code below, if I didn't store the `Tempfile` handles in the `handles` array I would get runtime error (`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`) when the `Zip::File.open` block closes:

```
handles = []
Zip::File.open(zip_file.path, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zip|
  # there are hundreds of @foos to iterate over
  @foos.each do |foo|
    cit_filename = generate_some_unique_filename
    cit_file = Tempfile.new(cit_filename)
    handles << cit_file
    cit_file.puts('some text')
    cit_file.close
    zip.add(cit_filename, cit_file.path)
  end
end # <- runtime error would have thrown at this point
handles = nil
```

Comment: Wow, this is really cool. You just saved my day. I kept running into the exact same issue as you before finding your solution.

Comment: I'm putting tempfile object in a hash to prevent GC. I never access the object inside the hash ever but the hash itself is accessed and is not garbage collected. I don't think ruby should be able to know if a hash key value is ever accessed or not. So I can't explain why the tempfile is gone like 40% of the occasions. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that you close the file within the loop (`cit_file.close`)... in addition, some `File` (and `TempFile`) methods that accept blocks will automatically close the file at the end of the block.

Answer (score 8):

The tempfile gets deleted when it's garbage collected (it isn't referenced any longer and memory cleanup is releasing the object).

As stated in the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html):

> When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is automatically deleted...

As long is you still hold a reference to the temporary object, you shouldn't worry about it being deleted prematurely.