# Temp files disappears when CarrierWave processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, temporary-files, rails-activejob

I created an ActiveJob to process my carrier waves uploads.  However, when I upload more than one image, I get the following error for the second file:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/tdavi/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20180830-392-z2s2i.jpg)
```

Here's the code in my controller:

```
if @post.save
  files = params[:post_attachments].map { |p|
    {image: p['photo'][:image].tempfile.path, description: p['photo'][:decription]}
  }
  ProcessPhotosJob.perform_later(@post.id, files.to_json)
  format.html { render :waiting }
end
```

And my ActiveJob

```
require 'json'

class ProcessPhotosJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(post_id, photos_json)
    post = Post.friendly.find(post_id)
    photos = JSON.parse photos_json

    photos.each do |p|
        src_file = File.new(p['image'])
        post.post_attachments.create!(:photo => src_file, :description => p[:description])
    end

    post.processed = true
    post.save
  end
end
```

When I upload only one file to upload, it works okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass Tempfile to the queued jobs.

First of all - TempFiles can be deleted automatically by Ruby ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#class-Tempfile-label-Explicit+close), [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237879/2039726))

If you would like to upload file(s) and process them later (in a background), then I would suggest you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705045/pass-file-to-active-job-background-job).